# Firebase: myDataRef.push() - controlling node names - dont like this: '-Ivpzk1cIzxb6ETuZuxw'

Tags: firebase

I am looking for a way to control the 'node names' in firebase

I have to push an json-String into the firebase db like:

```
  myDataRef.push(<?php print $item->as_json(true); ?>);
  myDataRef.push({"TEST": <?php print $item->as_json(true); ?>, ".priority": 1.0});
```

Question:

How can I modify this 'node names':

```
-Ivpzk1cIzxa6ETuZuxw
```

Thanks for any helpful suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to control names, use `set` instead:

```js
var myDataRef = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/TEST");
myDataRef.set(<?php print $item->as_json(true); ?>);
```

`push` is meant to autogenerate IDs that have the timestamp encoded in them and are therefore chronologically ordered. You usually don't need to use priorities with push-generated IDs since they're already ordered lexicographically.